# Add html to taxonomy_menu_block taxonomy terms

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to edit the html of the taxonomy terms printed from the module [taxonomy menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block).

Is there a way to add a theme wrapper or to override a template so I can add html to each and every taxonomy term?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this module it does not employ a theme template file so overriding with your own template file is not a possibility; therefore, you will need to use Drupals theming later and processing hooks in your theme to alter the HTML output of the module without hacking the module. A start would be to look at [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7)